# Python, create a function to control the process in another file python

Tags: python, controls

I created these three functions in python (**pool.py**, **funcA.py**, **config.py**). My intent is that having two python files I would like the two functions to interact. Specifically, I have the **pool.py** file which has a while loop inside that simulates an always active process that should be blocked when the **funcA.py** file is called separately. The config.py file is used to create a global variable and use this variable in both files, with **funcA.py** I go to modify these variables *cmd0* and *cmd1* and instead with the file **pool.py** I repeatedly read these variables and check if they change. If you want to test the operation you can take these files and open two terminals in one run **pool.py** and in the other, you can run the **funcA.py** file then you can change the content of the *cmd0* and *cmd1* variables in the **funcA.py** file while the **pool.py** function is still running on the other terminal and you can see that the output of the **pool.py** file updates immediately.
Now my question is how can I make the contents of the **funcA.py** file become a function and run it directly as a function and have the same result? That is the one that by launching the new function that is inside the **funcA.py** file I modify the output of the **pool.py** function that is running on the other terminal.

**config.py**

```
def init():
 global cmd0, cmd1
 cmd0 = ''
 cmd1 = ''
 return cmd0, cmd1
```

**pool.py**

```
 import os
 import time
 import sys
 import numpy as np
 import config
 import funcA
 from importlib import reload

 while True:

   funcA = reload(funcA)
   print(str(config.cmd0))
   print(str(config.cmd1))
   if config.cmd0 == 'start':
    print('stop')
    time.sleep(10)
```

**funcA.py**

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import config

config.cmd0 = 'start'
config.cmd1 = 'u1'
```

Comment: launching a new terminal would launch another python interpreter, it knows nothing about the content of the first python interpreter, and so your implementation (and the currently answer) won't work, may i ask what is the reason for this ? do you want to detect if a variable in another process changes like a process monitor ? or do you want to do some sort of process communication between two terminals ?

Comment: just as a note, communication between processes is usually done using the `socket` module, so if you intend to do this correctly you should learn how to use it in a client-server setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, the following is working:

**pool.py**

```
python
import os
import time
import sys
import numpy as np
import config
import funcA
from importlib import reload

while True:

  funcA = reload(funcA)
  funcA.change_values("cmd0", "cmd1")
  print(str(config.cmd0))
  print(str(config.cmd1))
  if config.cmd0 == 'start':
     print('stop')
     time.sleep(10)
```

**funcA.py**

```py
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import config

config.cmd0 = 'start'
config.cmd1 = 'u1'

def change_values(a, b):
    config.cmd0 = a  
    config.cmd1 = b
```

As you can see, the function `change_values` is called in the **pool.py** without any check, then the `cmd0` and `cmd1` will change immediately.

Comment: ok this solution works, if i'want call this python function via terminal for example "python funcA.py 'start' 'u1' ?

Comment: if you want to run `python funcA.py` from terminal and get the same behaviour just put the following line in the end of **funcA.py**: `change_values('value1', 'value2')`

Comment: sorry I explained myself badly. I would like to change the inputs from the terminal.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you want to do?? sorry i didnt understand what you want to do

Comment: python funcA.py 'input1' 'input2'

Comment: then you want top get the new values by command line. In this case, you can use `param1 = sys.argv[1]; param2 = sys.argv[2]; change_values(param1, param2)`. Note that argv is an array that represents the command line: the first element is the program name, the second element (in position 1) is the first param of the command and so on...